# How Facebook link preview happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

When you type a URL into facebook, it automatically comes up with the "post a link" feature. With most websites, it automatically loads a selection of images it pulls from somewhere in the page to go alongside the link and description. does anyone have an idea of how to implement that same feature for our own site without any FB API etc.. just javascript or JQuery ?

Comment: I've just released a client-side library for that purpose. Check it out: [bootstrap-linkpreview](https://github.com/Ekito/bootstrap-linkpreview)

Answer (score 16):

Due to security restrictions, JavaScript cannot load any page from any server. Facebook actually asks the *Facebook servers* for information about that page, and the servers in turn query the page to extract the information. You, too, will need a server-side implementation of this.

Aside from that, it's fairly simple: use an HTTP client library for your language of choice to connect to the provided URL, then use an HTML parsing library to extract the `title` tag, identify a significant piece of text in the `body` tag, and extract the `img` tag sources that seem the most appropriate.

Once your server is able to extract information about a page, it's a fairly simple exercise to call it through AJAX.

Comment: Victor is right. There's no way for JS to load and process a page from another server. You have to do an AJAX call to a page executing the HTML parsing which returns the information you need.

Comment: Yep, that has to be the only way to show the preview. What interests me is the image. Is there any mechanism to detect the most appropriate image to show as representative of the page?

Answer (score 13):

@Keshan.

I developed myself a Facebook Link Preview with PHP and jQuery that is on my website. Take a look... The source code is free... I didn't post the whole code here because they are many files... But if you prefer the code to be posted here, tell me and I'll post.

It's available on Github https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Facebook-Link-Preview

[Facebook Link Preview - PHP + jQuery](http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/)

Comment: Thanks !! i will have a look.

Comment: In fact. But they are not few codes. It also is available on Github https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Facebook-Link-Preview where many people have forked. Although my website provides a full explanation about this plugin, I'm not trying to generate visit flow to there.

Answer (score 8):

I think following steps are involved

- Using Javascript find the links in the written text
- From the found links get the last link in the text (FB shows only for last link)
- Using AJAX send this link detail to a server side page (PHP/ASP/JSP etc.)
- The server side page gets the required data (from Meta tags) including

  - Title (Preferably Open graph `og:title` if missing from `<title>`
  - Description (Preferably Open graph `og:description` if missing from `<meta name="description" ....`
  - Images (Preferably Open graph `og:image` if missing from `<img src=....`
- In PHP you can get these datas either using `curl` or `file_get_contents` and parse for required data detailed above. Not sure about other Language.
- Show the result thus found in the AJAX request.

Additionally I think FB stores the data, once found, in database and 1st queries there. This helps them to get faster result and hence same article shared and liked generate the image and details from the stored data.

You will need Javascript to show this preview in runtime (while you write in the textarea). However if you only need it after posting of data it can be done with pure server side language (you can avoid javascript) and following above steps just remove AJAX call.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly there aren’t that many services out there doing this. As the previous commenter posted, your browser can’t do this without a server element.

So, the workflow is really this:

1. Parse the inserted text to test it’s a valid URL
2. Whiz that URL value via AJAX to a bespoke service or roll your own.
3. The service (mine is written in .Net) loads up the page in memory and parses it with an DOM parser. I use the HTML Agility pack you could use AngleSharp etc.
4. You need to extract the Open graph meta elements with (typically) fall back to standard Meta Title/ Description et all.
5. Pack up all that OG goodness and return this model via AJAX
6. Put the returned values on screen as a preview.
7. If accepted write the logic to insert the values into your DB

If you are not up to creating the server object, there are third-party services that can do the retrieval bits:

http://unfurl.oroboro.com/

https://guteurls.de/

best of luck.