# Show a summary text/image from URL

Tags: javascript, html

When users add a link within their posts on my site, I want to show a summary text/image from the URL. This is commmonly done by facebook. But how is it done ?

Any JS library/ inbuilt solution that can help me ?

Comment: This has been asked already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767473/how-facebook-link-preview-happens

Answer (score 2):

1. Send the text the user has entered to your server
2. Have your server side code:

   1. Parse it for URLs
   2. Make HTTP requests for the URLs specified
   3. Extract a summary/images from them (using whatever algorithm you like)
   4. Include those in the response

Comment: A couple of performance tweaks I'm sure Facebook uses is to cache a result for a URL sharable among all users and/or have partner icons or images based on a domain, etc.

Comment: Quentin, Thanks! @Vector's solution looks more simpler to implement than anything. Are there any caveats with that or what are the advantages of your solution over that ?

Comment: @user01 — You wanted to show a *summary*, Vector's solution shows the *entire page* (unless X-Frames-Options blocks it from loading at all) and any JS in the page will run so it might framebust you and send the user away from your page entirely.

Comment: Can not believe this has been voted up 3 times!?

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery

```
$.get("www.google.com", function(data) { do what ever you want to do with the data });
```

Change the function to extract the page content.

Get function reference
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Other posts which can help

[Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

Comment: That won't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Please [see the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.".